# ASMX web-service work on both HTTP and HTTPs

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, soap, asmx

I have a soap web-service in asp.net. Currently the URL is http://www.mylink.org/webservices/abcws.asmx. I have a request from a client to make the webservice work in both HTTP and HTTPS. Does anybody know how to achieve this in asp.net.

Comment: ASMX is a legacy technology, and should not be used for new development. WCF or ASP.NET Web API should be used for all new development of web service clients and servers. One hint: Microsoft has retired the [ASMX Forum](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/asmxandxml/threads) on MSDN.

Comment: Thank you for the information.My company wanted to continue use the existing code.

Comment: The comment was more for future readers than for you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you enable SSL on IIS or whatever web server your are running the service on, the service will listen on HTTPS as well as HTTP.

However, your client will need to purchase a SSL certificate.

**Update**: You can get a free SSL certificate from https://letsencrypt.org/.

Comment: Thank you for your response.Do i have to make any change in the existing code?